# Java gson fromJson half the time showing SignatureParser.class source not found error

Tags: java, gson, fromjson

And the curious thing is that the other half of thetime it actually works... I simply don't get why this is happening.

For some more context, what I'm trying to do is to instanciate an objecto of the class Indexer defined as follows:

```
public class Indexer {

private String name;
private List<String> allTerms = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<double[]> fileVectors = new ArrayList<double[]>();
/* and the propper setters and getters*/
```

And here is were the instance is being loaded from a .json file.

```
public Indexer loadIndex(String indexPath) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new FatherFileReader().getFileContent(indexPath);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
        Indexer indexer = gson.fromJson(root, Indexer.class);
        System.out.println(indexer.getName());
        return indexer;

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

When I execute it, it does print the atribute name from the indexer object, but the second time I try, a tab right beside the console appears with the name SignatureParser.class appears with the following message. And the third time I try... it works again!! And so on... Also, it doesn't fall on the catch block, so it doesn't print the StackTrace and the program just halts and the tab pops up.

> Class File Editor
>   Source not found
>   The source attachment does not contain the source for the file SignaturesParser.class. You can change the source attachment by clicking the Change Attached Source below.

I don't know what's going on... I would be really thankfull for some help.

---

EDIT

I already got it to work consistently by running it as a Java aplication istead of running it with the eclipse debugger... I still am curious to know what's going on. But for now i', going to test with the java aplication runner.